# Are incomplete answers valid?

Tags: discussion, answers

My question here is regarding incomplete answers. There are a lot of questions that cannot be answered without a lot of work but what can be quite simple is to add in a general overview of how the particular part of the system works.

Is it ok to add these sort of answers that in the end point the user in the right direct but the user will still need some development skills to complete the task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion these questions would otherwise be closed as 'too broad' so pointing someone in the right direction is sufficient when it would take 100+ lines to come up with an answer

Comment: this sort of sounds like an incomplete answer.. :3

Comment: @easymoden00b but oh so valuable and wise so it adds so much to the question and community as a whole. :P Not an answer, just an opinion

Comment: flagged, downvoted..            (jk)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone one of us is here to provide silver plated complete, production tested solutions (that's what we do as our day job).

So yes, I think providing a broad outline that will lead to a solution is perfectly acceptable. The original question poster might even learn something in the process rather than just copying & pasting.